# Bundled file is not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, go, webpack

I am using Golang (Echo) for my backend and React for my frontend. When I bundle my code using webpack, the file is created; however, I am getting an error in my console when I go to localhost:3000 stating the bundle file cannot be found. This is the exact error message: GET http://localhost:3000/build/app.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED.

Here is my server:

```
func main() {
    env.SetEnvVars()

    e := echo.New()
    e.File("/", "server/static/index.html")

    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(os.Getenv("PORT")))
}
```

Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './client/main.jsx',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'server/static/build'),
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
  },
  ...
```

And the script tag in my index.html file is:

```
<script src="./build/app.bundle.js"></script>
```

The directory path regarding these files is currently:

```
/
  server/
    main.go
    static/
      index.html
      build/
        app.bundle.js
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `echo` server you've set up only serves one single path, the root path (`"/"`), by rendering the contents of the `index.html` file. Because you haven't set up any other handlers for that server, any request to a path other than the root will result in 404, including those requests made from the index page via script and link tags, e.g.; `<script src="./build/app.bundle.js"></script>`.

To be able to serve a request to a path like `"/static/build/app.bundle.js"` for example you need to tell the server how to do that by registering a new handler.

With the `echo` server you can use its [Static](https://godoc.org/github.com/labstack/echo#Echo.Static) method to do that.

```
e.Static("/static", "static")
```

Please keep in mind that the links you use in html tags, the location of the corresponding files on your machine, and the location from where you launched your app matters if you use relative paths like `./build/app.bundle.js`, and because of that the two arguments to `e.Static` may need to be somewhat different from the example here.

Here's a bit more [info](https://echo.labstack.com/guide/static-files).